# Negating bracketed character classes in Perl regular expressions and grep

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I'm attempting to solve a very simple problem - find strings in an array which only contain certain letters. However, I've run up against something in the behavior of regular expressions and/or `grep` that I don't get.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @test_data = qw(ant bee cat dodo elephant frog giraffe horse);

# Words wanted include these letters only. Hardcoded for demonstration purposes
my @wanted_letters = qw/a c d i n o t/;

# Subtract those letters from the alphabet to find the letters to eliminate.
# Interpolate array into a negated bracketed character class, positive grep
# against a list of the lowercase alphabet: fine, gets befghjklmpqrsuvwxyz.
my @unwanted_letters = grep(/[^@wanted_letters]/, ('a' .. 'z'));

# The desired result can be simulated by hardcoding the unwanted letters into a
# bracketed character class then doing a negative grep: matches ant, cat, and dodo.
my @works = grep(!/[befghjklmpqrsuvwxyz]/, @test_data);

# Doing something similar but moving the negation into the bracketed character
# class fails and matches everything.
my @fails1 = grep(/[^befghjklmpqrsuvwxyz]/, @test_data);

# Doing the same thing that produced the array of unwanted letters also fails.
my @fails2 = grep(/[^@unwanted_letters]/, @test_data);

print join ' ', @works; print "\n";
print join ' ', @fails1; print "\n";
print join ' ', @fails2; print "\n";
```

Questions:

- Why does `@works` get the correct result but not `@fails1`? The [`grep` docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) suggest the former, and the [negation section of `perlrecharclass`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Negation) suggests the latter, although it uses `=~` in its example. Is this something specifically to do with using `grep`?
- Why does `@fails2` not work? Is it something to do with array vs list context? It otherwise looks the same as the subtraction step.
- Besides that, is there a pure regex way to achieve this that avoids the subtraction step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `fails` are fixed with the addition of anchors `^` and `$` and quantifier `+`

These both work:

```
my @fails1 = grep(/^[^befghjklmpqrsuvwxyz]+$/, @test_data);
my @fails2 = grep(/^[^@unwanted_letters]+$/, @test_data);
```

Keep in mind that `/[^befghjklmpqrsuvwxyz]/` or `/[^@unwanted_letters]/` only matches ONE character. Adding `+` means as many as possible. Adding `^` and `$` means all characters from the start to the end of the string.

With `/[@wanted_letters]/` you will return a match if there is a single wanted character (even with unwanted characters in the string) -- the logical equivalent to [any](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#any). Compare to `/^[@wanted_letters]+$/` where all the letters need to be in the set of `@wanted_letters` and is the equivalent of [all](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#all).

[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/UWFs10/1/) only ONE character so `grep` fails.

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/Aw4e3C/1) quantifier means more than one but no anchor - grep fails

[Demo3](https://regex101.com/r/BCPH7i/1) Anchors and quantifier - expected result.

Once you understand [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) only match ONE character and [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the WHOLE string and [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for everything extending the match to the anchors, you can directly grep just with wanted letters:

```
my @wanted = grep(/^[@wanted_letters]+$/, @test_data);
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains it perfectly. Evidently when I was looking at [perlrecharclass](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Bracketed-Character-Classes) I accidentally skipped over where it introduces them as matching a single character. That single match is exactly what I was hoping could be achieved.

Comment: I think I was writing regex's for a while before I really *got* that a character class was a set that only matches a single character. It is a common oversight.

Comment: Full disclosure: I used to do Perl for a living and I absolutely already knew this. But somewhere in the decade+ since then, I forgot  Thanks for applying a bit of oil to a rusty tin man.

Comment: Your Perl code itself shows the professional background. Beautiful!

Comment: You're too kind!

Answer (score 4):

You're matching something outside the character set anywhere in the string. But it can still have characters in the character set somewhere else in the string. For instance, if the test word is `elephant`, the negated character class matches the `a` character.

If you want to test the whole string, you need to quantify it and anchor to the ends.

```
grep(/^[^befghjklmpqrsuvwxyz]*$/, @test_data);
```

Translated into English, it's the difference between "word contains no characters in the set" and "word contains a character not in the set".